# What's the best exercise to get more well defined abs, a.k.a Muscle hypertrophy

Tags: weightlifting, abdominals

I've searched the internet for core exercises for building abs, and I'm a little bit confused. Some say that sit-ups is great for getting well defined abs, while some say you only get better at doing sit-ups, and nothing else. I understand that doing sit-ups is better than nothing, and that it's building up the abs in some way. My question is what is the best exercise for getting as big/well defined abs as possible? And how many reps and sets?

Comment: Have you checked the questions tagged "abdominals", see http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/abdominals?

Answer (score 1):

There's an old saying that Abs are built in the kitchen...and it's true.  To see well defined abs you need to have low/athletic level body fat (some say single digit some in say your body fat needs to be in the teens).

You work your abs by doing situps, planks, squats, deadlifts, etc. Unlike other muscles, abs are dense and do not GROW like your biceps, calf, back muscles...they have a different purpose, which is to support your body under tension (from what I understand they're more layered and dense).

You can also NOT target certain body areas to reduce fat just there and everyone stores fat a little different.  SO, if you really want abs, go on a progressive weight lifting program, join myFittnessPal to get your nutrition in line and don't give up.